# When I use UpdateData(False) in a timer, one multiline edit box of the window is twinkling

Tags: mfc

When I use UpdateData(False) in a timer, one multiline edit box of the window is twinkling.
What i do, can let the edit box don't reply the UpdaeData(False)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Regardless of what it is, what you have implemented is wrong, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using UpdateData in a timer? You should not.
It will wipe off any user input.
What are you trying to achieve?